# Print JSON file from JSP

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have JSP page that should print JSON file.
Here is the directive

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json;" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

and one line of the code: out.println(result); //Results is JSON string from DB

But every time when I call the jsp page the result is a JSP file instead of application/json

And then I try to load JSON from the JSP:

```
.ajax({
   url: url_res,
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(value, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                     alert(textStatus+" "+value+" "+jqXHR);
```

And always I get NULL in the vale var.

PLS help, i need this for my faculty project..

Comment: If you are using Firefox then can you please check Error console (Ctrl+Shift+j) to see whether any js error in JSON string ?

Answer (score 0):

If you directly put the jsp page in browser and the returned source code is plain json, then your jsp page is just fine.

try to testing the data in json by alert(textStatus+" "+value.something+" "+jqXHR);